# Unable to connect "broker:29092" kafka on docker

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka, airflow, broker

This is the .yml file i made based on project on youtube.

```
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
      image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.5.0
      hostname: zookeeper
      container_name: zookeeper
      ports:
        - "2181:2181"
      environment:
        ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
        ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      healthcheck:
        test: ['CMD', 'bash', '-c', "echo 'ruok' | nc localhost 2181"]
        interval: 10s
        timeout: 5s
        retries: 5
      # networks:
      #   - confluent

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:7.5.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      zookeeper:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
      - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,CONNECTIONS_FROM_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,CONNECTIONS_FROM_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
    # networks:
    #   - confluent
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "bash", "-c", 'nc -z localhost 9092' ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.5.0
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      broker:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081
    # networks:
    #   - confluent
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8081/" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:7.5.0
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
      broker:
        condition: service_healthy
      schema-registry:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      # CONFLIENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      PORT: 9021
    # networks:
    #   - confluent
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9021/health" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
```

And i use airflow in docker to connect broker with :

```
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['broker:29092'], max_block_ms=5000, api_version=(0, 10, 2))
```

What i got from airlfow dags log :

```
ERROR - An error occured: KafkaTimeoutError: Failed to update metadata after 5.0 secs.

[2024-01-30, 16:26:38 UTC] {conn.py:1527} WARNING - DNS lookup failed for broker:29092, exception was [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution. Is your advertised.listeners (called advertised.host.name before Kafka 9) correct and resolvable?

[2024-01-30, 16:26:38 UTC] {conn.py:315} ERROR - DNS lookup failed for broker:29092 (0)
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Try without the port.

Comment: you mean like this :
`
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['broker'], max_block_ms=5000, api_version=(0, 10, 2))
`